# When can the lower bound of a confidence interval be used?

Tags: r, classification, python, confidence-interval, inference

I'm performing analysis on the data found in the NHANES package in R.

One of the vectors describes the estimated number of days that participants drank alcoholic beverages.

[image]

I want to classify them as Alcohol_Disorder/No_Acohol_Disorder.

The 95% confidence interval is (65.30, 72.36).

I feel compelled to subtract each number by 15 and THEN classify based on whether the new number is greater than 416 (drinks 8 drinks per week).

Thoughts? How does my thinking sound?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are trying to do. The data are on how many days per year someone drinks alcohol, not on how many drinks per day or week they have. For all we know, they could be having a single drink on many days, or binge-drink many drinks on a few days. I don't see how this connects to subtracting 15, or looking at 8 drinks per week. (Also, I don't see how this connects to a confidence interval for the mean of the days on which participants drink. You don't want to classify an "average participant", after all.)

Comment: @StephanKolassa This is the description for the variable: "Estimated number of days over the past year that participant drank alcoholic beverages." I simply want to classify heavy drinkers. Do you have any ideas how I could do that?

Comment: You can't based on the data. You have one person drinking every day of the year (364). That might be a glass of wine per day or it might be a bottle of spirit per day. You have another person drinking once per week (52). That might be a glass of beer per week or they might binge-drink at the weekend.

Comment: @Roland Thank you!

Comment: Can you use the *AlcoholDay* variable for what you want to do ?

Comment: @SalMangiafico oh my! Didn't even notice that var. Thanks so much.

Comment: That being said, you probably can't convert *AlcoholDay* directly to alcohol use disorder.

Comment: Also, this doesn't at all address the heart of your question, which had to do with using confidence intervals to classify individuals.

Comment: @SalMangiafico Would it make sense to classify someone as a drinker if they, let's say, drank 'x' amount for _AlcoholDay_ & drank at least 'x' # of days for _AlcoholYear_? The confidence interval issue would be irrelevant if so.

Comment: Yes, you could do that. You might want to use something like cluster analysis to see if individual cluster along these axes.  Or you could use your own cutoffs.